# Is there a way to use the Olive framework in a Xamarin application?

Tags: xamarin, .net-core, olive

We are using the Olive framework in a .NET Core app.

Is there a way to use the Olive framework in a Xamarin application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olive is made of some 30 or so components:
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Olive

Most of them are .Net Standard and so usable in Xamarin. But some of them are .net Core 2.1 only.

If you need the common components of the framework in your project you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

from their [home page](https://github.com/Geeksltd/Olive)

> Olive is a framework built top of .NET for more productive cross
>   platform software development in .NET solutions. It provides a whole
>   set of productivity tools to make .NET development easier, cleaner and
>   more expressive. It's available under the GPLv3 license. Olive is a
>   .NET Standard 2.0 library and so compatible with .NET Framework 4.6.1,
>   .NET Core 2.0, Mono 5.4, Xamarin.iOS 10.14, Xamarin.Mac 3.8,
>   Xamarin.Android 7.5 and UWP.

It specifically mentions support for Xamarin Android, iOS and Mac